# Some part of laptop screen is not working after upgrading the Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: upgrade, laptop, screen, 23.10, button

Top right corner of screen is not working.

Unable to minimize, close the browser[Google chrome, firefox]

Comment: Does this behavior persist after a reboot?

Comment: Yes, after upgrading the OS to 23.10